# Smarty include tpl with dynamic content?

Tags: php, smarty

i have a little problem with smarty, but don't know how to fix this.

This is my index.tpl

```
<body>
    {include file='header.tpl'}
    {include file='leftmenu.tpl'}
    <div id=content>
    {include file="news.tpl" }
    {include file="rightmenu.tpl"}
</body>
```

My problem there is this line

```
<div id=content>
    {include file="news.tpl" }
```

`news.php` is a file which should display `news.tpl` , because it is my newssystem.

In `news.php`, i query the mysql database and give the result to `news.tpl`.

But when i write the above line, the `news.tpl` don't know where the result comes from.

Hope someone could help.

Comment: You have to move the `news.php` code to `index.php`. Or else include `news.php` in `index.php` and don't define the `template tenderer` path there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do something like this, `Smarty_Data` will help you

```
$data = new Smarty_Data;
$data->assign('foo','bar');
$smarty->display('news.tpl',$data);
```

Sent your `news` array to `assign` function.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a good alternative. You can simply add the PHP tag for including the PHP file

> {php} include "news.php"; {/php}

Comment: No, really, because i have to enable php in tpl.